# Memory leak on UIImageView after ViewController deinit

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uiimageview

I have a ViewController with subview of imageView of filling whole of vc , when I present new VC and dismiss the old VC , deinit of oldVC is called but memory remained and instrument shows me is something related to imageio , the main problem is why deinit of oldvc is called but image reamins on memory.. this is my oldvc code:

```
class Vc1: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var vcimage: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    vcimage.image = UIImage.init(named: "splash")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
@IBAction func tovc2(_ sender: Any) {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc2")
    AnimateTovc(ViewControllerToAnimate: vc!, vctoDissmiss: self)
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    print("memory warning")
}
func AnimateTovc(duration:Float = 0.5,Animateoption:UIViewAnimationOptions = .transitionFlipFromLeft,ViewControllerToAnimate vc:UIViewController,vctoDissmiss: UIViewController?,completion : @escaping ()->Void = {} ){
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    UIView.transition(with: appDelegate.window!, duration: TimeInterval(duration), options: Animateoption , animations: { () -> Void in
        appDelegate.window!.rootViewController = vc
    }, completion:{ isfinished in
        completion()
        vctoDissmiss?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    })
}
deinit {
    print("removed \(self) from memory")
}
}
```

the weird part is memory gets freed in newvc when app gets in background and imageio part is release from memory.

Comment: Be aware that the simulator has memory leaks that are due to bugs in the simulator but that don't occur on an actual device. If you are getting memory leaks that don't make sense, be sure to test on a device and see it the leak still occurs.

Comment: @DuncanC unfortunately no the problem exist on real device too .

Comment: Try creating the image with ```UIImage(contentsOfFile: pathForImage)```

Comment: @AllenR yes! the memory gets free with using this method .. so I have use this method whenever I have quality images or whenever I want use an image once?

Comment: Yea I really wish there was a better api. It really should be made more obvious that the image is being cached by the method signature. Use it sparingly and when you will need to use the same image over and over again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Allen, the problem is solved by using `UIImage(contentsOfFile:)`.

According to Apple docs:

> Use the init(named:in:compatibleWith:) method (or the init(named:) method) to create an image from an image asset or image file located in your app’s main bundle (or some other known bundle). Because these methods cache the image data automatically, they are especially recommended for images that you use frequently.
>
> Use the imageWithContentsOfFile: or init(contentsOfFile:) method to
>   create an image object where the initial data is not in a bundle.
>   These methods load the image data from disk each time, so you should
>   not use them to load the same image repeatedly.

Comment: But this is not the real answer. The real answer is that this was never a leak and you shouldn't have been concerned about it. As you rightly said in your question, the runtime manages the cached memory for you. So go on using `init(named:)` and be happy.

Comment: @matt my iphone was getting crashes due to memory , but it solved after using UIImage(contentsOfFile:)